# What happens if you call refresh() on Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract after the row has been deleted from the db?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I'm using Zend Framework version 1.x

The documentation for the `refresh` method of `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` says only:

```
Refreshes properties from the database.
```

My question is what this method will return if the row has been deleted from the database in the meantime (ie. by some other process)?

Will it be able to handle that situation by either returning null or throwing an exception?

Thanks,
Jakob

Comment: You can easily test it... And tell us the result! No? I think the result will be `false` or `NULL`.

Comment: Will do if nobody beats me to it ;-)

Comment: In my mind, refresh will make a find by the row primary column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the `resfresh()` just calls `_refresh()` and if `$row === null` returns an `Exception`.

```
protected function _refresh()
    {
        $where = $this->_getWhereQuery();
        $row = $this->_getTable()->fetchRow($where);

        if (null === $row) {
            require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Row/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception('Cannot refresh row as parent is missing');
        }

        $this->_data = $row->toArray();
        $this->_cleanData = $this->_data;
        $this->_modifiedFields = array();
    }
```

Comment: "Throws an exception" sounds like the correct answer, glancing at the source code. 'Cannot refresh row as parent is missing' probably means that refresh would also fail if any of the dependent rows in linked tabled have gone missing.